# export 2 grid views in to a single worksheet in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, export

Currently, I have 2 data tables that are being exported into 2 separate worksheets. How do I export these 2 data tables into a single worksheet? Anyone? I've been having a tough time getting this puzzle solved.

```
private DataTable SkyvisionMachineData()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Media_OperationsConnectionString9"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT CorporateName, Region FROM MACHINE"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        dt.TableName = "Region";
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private DataTable SkyvisionZoneData()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Media_OperationsConnectionString9"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))

            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT CorporateName, Spare, Region FROM  dbo.Machine WHERE CorporateName LIKE @CorporateName OR Region like @Region"))

                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CorporateName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Label1.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Region", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = Label1.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        dt.TableName = "Machine";
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public DataSet getDataSetExportToExcel()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            DataTable Machine = new DataTable("Machine Data");
            Machine = SkyvisionMachineData();

            DataTable Region = new DataTable("Skyvision Zone Data");
            Region = SkyvisionZoneData();

            ds.Tables.Add(Machine);
            ds.Tables.Add(Region);
            return ds;

        }
        protected void ExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = getDataSetExportToExcel();
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
                wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= DBSearchReport.xlsx

    ");
                using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you familiar with how to Merge using DataTable..? there are plenty of examples on how to do this online

Comment: Unfortunately not. I would really appreciate if you could show me how it is done in my scenario.

Comment: I just told you what you should do.. do a simple google search on how to merge datatables what's the problem also if you do not want to do that then google how to construct a UNION statement and I would suggest you convert the sql into a Stored procedure as well

Comment: Thanks for your time, but "google it" is not helpful to me at all.

Comment: I need to get 2 data tables and stick them into 1 worksheet. That is all I am trying to accomplish. I understand there are different routes out there, but merging 2 databases doesn't work for me.

Comment: why not.. then I guess you will be on struggling then..because like I have said there are plenty of examples out there and this is not a `Do my work for me site` nor a `Code Service Provider` site..

Comment: if you can get the first datatable filled with the first query..and the second datatable filled with the second query.. then why can't you just construct a UNION Query or google how to merge 2 datatables... ?

Comment: I Would like to have 2 separate "GridView" style tables located one underneath another in the excel document. That is the reason I don't want to merge or unite 2 databases.

Comment: No worries, I will figure this out somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: this can be done I have done this many times with a DataGridView along with using the `ITextSharp` dll.. you need to stop expecting others to do your work and do some research. you clearly have stopped at I don't know how.. once again I am respectfully giving you 3 different options now

Comment: Thanks MethodMan, I will figure this out on my own

Answer (score 1):

The Merge method takes the values from the second table and merges them in with the first table, so the first will now hold the values from both.

If you want to preserve both of the original tables, you could copy the original first, then merge:

```
dtAll = new DataTable();
...
dtAll.Merge(dtOne);
dtAll.Merge(dtTwo);
dtAll.Merge(dtThree);
```

This technique is useful in a loop where you want to iteratively merge data tables:

```
DataTable dtAllCountries = new DataTable();

foreach(String strCountry in listCountries)
{
    DataTable dtCountry = getData(strCountry); //Some function that returns a data table
    dtAllCountries.Merge(dtCountry);
}
```